# constructor PersonaMapper cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, mapper

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public abstract class PersonaMapper {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final ContactRepository contactRepository;

    private final PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    private final TypeContactRepository typeContactRepository;

    private final  UserRepository userRepository;
    public abstract RegisterView toDTO(Person entity);
    }
```

I have a problem,

When I run the clean install, it gives me the following error:

**constructor PersonaMapper in class me.angular.service.mapper.person.PersonaMapper cannot be applied to given types;**